# Move large number of small blobs to different azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I found quite some answers to copy blobs between azure storage accounts. I know of the cmdlet using `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy`. However, I have > 20 million files to copy between two storage accounts in the same data center and it seems to take forever (it is copying since more than a week) since it starts each file copy process separately.

Furthermore, I found that in the most current version of the Azure tools (7.4), the cmdlet downloads the full file list (to memory) and only then starts with the copy process. So it not only takes forever but uses large amount of memory. The same is also true if I use AzCopy.

Thus my question: what is a good possibility (that actually really works!) to copy large amounts of files of which each is not that big between two storage accounts in the same data center? Or maybe you know of parameters to set when using the cmdlets (the documentation is awful and not updated)?

Comment: Is writing your own code a possibility instead of relying on readymade solution?

Comment: Yes, sure! But would that change anything?

Comment: I would think so. You could optimize the code. For example, you mentioned that the cmdlet first lists all blobs in the container and keeps them in memory. Your code could fetch a list of 5000 blobs, copy them and then move on to next set of blobs. Also you could initiate multiple requests in parallel. Though each file will be copied individually so you can't save there but that being an async server side process is not really in your control.

Comment: One question why do you need to copy them to another container? seems an odd operation to need in the same data center.

Comment: @Dreamwalker Blobs are being copied from one storage account to another. Seems a very legitimate operation.

Comment: its because we were using a demo account that expires in a few weeks and now we have our own company account that we will use in the future

Comment: @GauravMantri yes I quite agree it was the number he needed to copy.  And he confirmed my suspicion it was a subscription reason :).  Contact Microsoft support they can switch the subscription to the other account I think it's under the billing section.

Comment: +1 @Dreamwalker. Microsoft Support can move contents of an entire subscription to another one. I have done this twice and they have been quite efficient at doing this. In my case, both times the request was fulfilled in less than 4 hours.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! In that case I will contact Microsoft Support directly.